# multiple files, multiprocessing and sliding window

Tags: python

I have a a list of files, (sometimes just one) and I want to process every n lines in parallel from each file with a sliding-window. 
I do not want to use multiprocessing through files since in some cases there could be less files than cores available.

Next I want to store the output of every sliding-window in a list (for random values). I have done this so far and it works fine but there are issues.

It would be great if I could change `pool.map` and use  `pool.something_else` that allows multiple parameters for my function (file, sliding window size and j).

I tried with `pool.apply_async` but when I do `pool.join` it takes too long time and I guess there is something wrong. Next step I would like to compare the output values (mean and std) by iterating through all file swith a sliding window: `all_segments`.

In a shorter description:

- For 10 random values iterate through file with a selected window
- Calculate mean for window and store the output into a list. For the list calculation the mean of the means and standard deviation.
- For every sliding window in files, calculate the mean and calculate a z-score against the previous mean and standard deviation obtained.

  ```
  def random_segments(j):
                  cov_list=[]
                  cov = []
                  lines = list(islice(f, j, j+1000))
                  for line in lines:
                          cov.append(float(line.split("\t")[2]))

                  mc1 = sum(cov)/len(cov)
                  cov_list.append(mc1)
                  return cov_list

  def all_segments(j):
          cov_list=[]
          cov = []
          lines = list(islice(f, j, j+1000))
          for line in lines:
                  cov.append(float(line.split("\t")[2]))
          mc2 = sum(cov)/len(cov)
          z = (mc2 - mean) / sd
          print (z)
          if z > 10 or z < -10:
                  print (line)



          if __name__ == '__main__':
          for cv_file in os.listdir("."):

                   if cv_file.endswith(".coverage.out"):
                           f = open(cv_file, 'r').readlines()
                           if args.ws == False:
                                   args.ws = 1000
                           size = len(f)
                           print (cv_file + "\t" + str(size))
                           perc= float(args.rn)/100 * int(size)
                           perc = perc // 1
                           print(perc)
                           pool=mp.Pool(int(args.proc))
                           rn=[random.randint(1,int(size)-args.ws) for _ in range(10)]
                           data = pool.map(random_segments, [i for i in rn])
                           data = [ent for sublist in data for ent in sublist]
                           sd, variance, mean = mean_std(data)
  ```

Comment: what do you mean with window here? Do you just mean a new process?

Comment: I mean a sliding-window as a single statement. when processing the file, instead of reading and processing line by line It will process n lines at a time

Comment: is `n` the number of processes you want to run?

Comment: n is the window size